# Options on display of text at 45 degree angle in browser

Tags: c#, jquery, html, css, text

I have a requirement to display text at a 45 degree angle in the browser.
The text is selected via ajax calls from a selection of a lot of values.
Text varies in length up to 100 characters.  Need to display the first part and the last few characters (I can figure this part out).
For example:
"This is the text and it can be quite long...end part of text"

I will have from 1 to 6 of these strings.
For a example, think of a table with the header text, quite lengthy, displayed at a 45 degree angle from bottom left to upper right.

Would like to be cross browser IF possible but MUST work on IE6 and IE8 in compatibility mode.  Target base upgrade from IE6 is out of my control.

Would like a client side ONLY solution if at all possible. Text is pulled from server via ajax, and comes from a database with 15,000+ different text string values and will grow to over 185,000 text values in the future.

Think of a table with the header text items displayed in an upwards direction stacked on columns that would be too narrow to display the text.

Considered options:
VML
Seems to work, but does NOT seem to respect the style size for the font, short strings are large font, longer are smaller, and I want them to be all the same size.

Example code:

```
<v:shape style="position: absolute; top: 25px; left: 50px; width: 300px; height: 300px;
        antialias: true" coordsize="300,300">
            <v:path textpathok="True" v="m 0,300 l 300,0" />
            <v:fill on="True" color="#0101FF" />
            <v:stroke on="false" />
            <v:textpath on="True" fitpath="true" string="My text string, quite long in length and of various length...end of text"
             style="font:normal normal bold 8pt Arial" />
        </v:shape>
```

SVG - does not work in IE without a plugin

JPG, GIF - requires round trip to server to create the graphic, impacts performance.

Processing.js http://processingjs.org/

Explorer Canvas: http://excanvas.sourceforge.net/

Do not know much (anything) about Processing.js or excanvas beyond reading the web sites text.

Positional type option as described here: http://jdstiles.com/java/angledtext2.html

Flash - not really an option here.

What Other options exist for this?

Other info:
Have jQuery here already.  Using it to do the ajax part.
Server side is asp.net c# .Net 2.0 framework (will upgrade in near future)

Edit1: Current sample of VML which seems to work for the target audience (NOT cross browser, uses VML which is fast on the target browser though)

```
<v:shape style="position: absolute; top: 25px; left: 50px; width: 300px; height: 300px;
                antialias: true" coordsize="300,300">
    <v:path textpathok="True" v="m 0,300 l 300,150" />
    <v:fill on="True" color="#0101FF" />
    <v:stroke on="false" />
    <v:textpath on="True" fitpath="false" string="My text string, quite long in length and of various length...end of text"
         style="v-text-align:left; font:normal normal 8pt Arial" />
</v:shape>
```

Comment: I don't think these two methods of font replacement will rotate your text, but they are interesting alternatives: sIFR (http://www.mikeindustries.com/blog/sifr/) and cufon (http://wiki.github.com/sorccu/cufon/about)

Comment: @fudgey -Thanks for pointing those two out.  The first uses flash and I want to stay away from that.  The second uses the SVG and VML technologies - since I have the VML option directly here, that will work at the sacrifice of the cross browser compatibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely the text in your VML example is changing size in size because you have **fitpath="true"** ? If you remove it then it respects the size you have set. You can then use the **v-text-align:left** style attribute to left align it if you need.

Comment: Thanks James, will try that, I am obviously not an expert VML person at this point :)

Comment: Sorry if I sounded a little rude. To be honest I don't have much experience of VML either.

Hope it works anyway.

Comment: I did not take it as rude at all, and it seems to be working.
Keeping this open for now to see if other options pop up.

Comment: Accepting this answer, as it fixes my original issue with the VML and if I need, I can always move to SVG emulation using some of the libraries that support SVG and VML combination for cross browser.

Answer (score 1):

You can't create true angled text on the client-side, but [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20170119055343if_/http://jdstiles.com/java/angledtext2.html) is as close as you can get.  The most reliable solution would be to have a script on the server side that takes a string of text as input, creates an image with the text at an angle (using some graphics library), and then streams the image in the response.

Comment: @Josh Stodola - thanks for pointing out the positional option from Uncle Jim, probably not very viable in my case due to the need to place each character as my strings are up to 100 characters and we might have several of these on my page.  Still worth a note though.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out Raphael Js library

http://raphaeljs.com/text-rotation.html

It abstracts the use of VML (for IE) and SVG (for all other browsers). It also plays nicely with jQuery.